# ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721 oracle bug

Tags: oracle

I have a customer table data,Here is some data that I have.
This is the customer table that I have, I wrote the primary key constraint to the customers table like below 
and here is the data of the savings table
I want to update the classification data in the customers table corresponding to the money in the savings table
A> 5000000000 5000000000 <B <10000000000 c> 100000000000 
This is the code that I did, I don't understand why it reported an error here, can you indicate my error?
It gives my error on a very large line, but in fact I did not write that line

```
update customer 
set classifi = (
  SELECT (
   CASE WHEN saving.money < 5000000000 THEN 'Grade C' WHEN saving.money 
   BETWEEN 5000000001 AND 10000000000 THEN 'Grade B' ELSE 'Grade A' END) AS 
   RANK FROM saving;
  ) 
where customer_id =10;
```

Comment: Please don't paste images, provide code as formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266 And please provide the full error message. Show us which line 1721 is

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sorry

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit update customer set classifi = (SELECT 
       (CASE
           WHEN saving.money < 5000000000
           THEN
              'Grade C'
           WHEN saving.money BETWEEN 5000000001 AND 10000000000
           THEN
              'Grade B'
           ELSE
              'Grade A'
        END) AS RANK
  FROM saving;)
  where customer_id =10;

Comment: Please don't put additional information as comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You statement is

```
update customer set classifi = (
    SELECT (CASE 
       WHEN saving.money < 5000000000 THEN 'Grade C' 
       WHEN saving.money BETWEEN 5000000001 AND 10000000000 THEN 'Grade B' 
       ELSE 'Grade A' END) AS RANK 
    FROM saving;) 
where customer_id = 10;
```

Remove the internal semicolon:

```
update customer set classifi = (
    SELECT (CASE 
       WHEN saving.money < 5000000000 THEN 'Grade C' 
       WHEN saving.money BETWEEN 5000000001 AND 10000000000 THEN 'Grade B' 
       ELSE 'Grade A' END) AS RANK 
    FROM saving) 
where customer_id = 10;
```

However, it will work only if table `saving` has one row only. Is this the case?

Comment: No, it has quite a few rows, which means that the code is wrong because there are many rows in the table